# PyCurl installed but not found

Tags: python, curl, libcurl, pycurl

I've been trying to install pycurl in a virtualenv with easy_install, and it appears to install correctly:

```
(xxx) $ easy_install pycurl
Searching for pycurl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
Best match: pycurl 7.19.0
Downloading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Processing pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Running pycurl-7.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-B2W9dY/pycurl-7.19.0/egg-dist-tmp-RmIsVr
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.19.7)
src/pycurl.c:85:4: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine which " "library was used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause random crashes on SSL requests"
src/pycurl.c: In function ‘do_multi_info_read’:
src/pycurl.c:2843: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_string’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to char * for this info
src/pycurl.c: In function ‘multi_socket_callback’:
src/pycurl.c:2355: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_string’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to char * for this info
In function ‘util_curl_unsetopt’,
    inlined from ‘do_curl_unsetopt’ at src/pycurl.c:1551:
src/pycurl.c:1476: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_setopt_err_CURLSH’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a CURLSH* argument for this option
gcc (GCC) 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding pycurl 7.19.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for pycurl
Finished processing dependencies for pycurl
```

However, when trying to use, I get the following error:

```
(xxx) $ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Sep 12 2011, 13:51:42) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

Despite the fact that I can clearly see a `pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg` in my `~/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated!

Distribution is Amazon Linux (EC2, 64 bit), Python is 2.7, installed from source. curl, libcurl and libcurl-dev are all supplied by the Amazon yum repos and are at version 7.19.7-26.20.

I can't install pycurl package provided by the Amazon repos because the distro-supplied version of python is 2.6, and my project runs on 2.7.

It is not a path issue, the contents of sys.path is as follows:

```
>>> import sys; sys.path
['', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygeoip-0.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/daryl_lib-1.8.4-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xxx-1.8.4-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/dealutils-1.5.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.0.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/fm2c-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/affiliatewindow-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/icodes-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/meld3-0.6.7-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-1.2-py2.7.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/root', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python27.zip', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: what do you get from sys.path ?

Comment: Tomasso: added sys.path output to main question since comments box is too short. It's not a path issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have managed (with some help) so solve the problem. The problem is that after installation, the pycurl.so is not copied to the site-packages for this virtualenv.

When installing via `pip -v install pycurl`, the following output is given:

```
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
  Using version 7.19.0 (newest of versions: 7.19.0, 7.19.0, 7.18.2, 7.18.1, 7.16.4, 7.16.2.1, 7.16.2, 7.16.1, 7.15.5.1)
  Downloading pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz (71Kb): 71Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycurl
        Using curl-config (libcurl 7.19.7)
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pycurl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl
    Using curl-config (libcurl 7.19.7)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/curl
    copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/curl
    running build_ext
    building 'pycurl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/opt/python2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/pycurl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o
    src/pycurl.c:85:4: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine which " "library was used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause random crashes on SSL requests"
    src/pycurl.c: In function ‘do_multi_info_read’:
    src/pycurl.c:2843: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_string’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to char * for this info
    src/pycurl.c: In function ‘multi_socket_callback’:
    src/pycurl.c:2355: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_string’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to char * for this info
    In function ‘util_curl_unsetopt’,
        inlined from ‘do_curl_unsetopt’ at src/pycurl.c:1551:
    src/pycurl.c:1476: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_setopt_err_CURLSH’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a CURLSH* argument for this option
    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o -L/opt/python2.7/lib -lcurl -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycurl.so unknown option: --static-libs Usage: curl-config [OPTION] Available values for OPTION include: --ca ca bundle install path --cc compiler --cflags pre-processor and compiler flags --checkfor [version] check for (lib)curl of the specified version --features newline separated list of enabled features --help display this help and exit --libs library linking information --prefix curl install prefix --protocols newline separated list of enabled protocols --version output version information --vernum output the version information as a number (hexadecimal)
    gcc (GCC) 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)
    Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    running install_lib
    creating /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curl
    copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/curl/__init__.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curl
    byte-compiling /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curl/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    running install_data
    copying ChangeLog -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl
    copying COPYING -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl
    copying COPYING2 -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl
    copying INSTALL -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl
    copying README -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl
    copying TODO -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl
    copying doc/curlshareobject.html -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/html
    copying doc/pycurl.html -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/html
    copying doc/curlobject.html -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/html
    copying doc/curlmultiobject.html -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/html
    copying doc/callbacks.html -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/html
    copying examples/retriever.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying examples/file_upload.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying examples/linksys.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying examples/xmlrpc_curl.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying examples/retriever-multi.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying examples/sfquery.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying examples/basicfirst.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/examples
    copying tests/test.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_ftp.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_share.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi5.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi_timer.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_post.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_gtk.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_post3.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_debug.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi4.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_cb.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi_vs_thread.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_stringio.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_xmlrpc.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi_socket_select.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi6.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi_socket.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/util.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi3.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_internals.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_post2.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_memleak.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_multi2.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_socketopen.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    copying tests/test_getinfo.py -> /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/share/doc/pycurl/tests
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pycurl.egg-info
    writing pycurl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pycurl.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pycurl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pycurl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pycurl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pycurl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Copying pycurl.egg-info to /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl-7.19.0-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to '/tmp/pip-lEWzoB-record/install-record.txt'
Successfully installed pycurl
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/xxx/build...
```

The key error here is: 
`gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o -L/opt/python2.7/lib -lcurl -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycurl.so unknown option: --static-libs Usage: curl-config [OPTION] Available values for OPTION include: --ca ca bundle install path --cc compiler --cflags pre-processor and compiler flags --checkfor [version] check for (lib)curl of the specified version --features newline separated list of enabled features --help display this help and exit --libs library linking information --prefix curl install prefix --protocols newline separated list of enabled protocols --version output version information --vernum output the version information as a number (hexadecimal)`

Which shows that `curl-config` is being called with the argument `--static-libs`, which it fails to recognise and instead prints it's 'usage' output. Most importantly, it is returning a non-error-code output which makes the compiler assume the `pycurl.so` compilation was successful.

This is described in more detail [here](http://yz.mit.edu/wp/cute-silent-failure-building-pycurl/)

The solution to this problem was to modify the pycurl's setup.py and change line 101 to read `--libs` instead of `--static-libs`. This causes `pycurl.so` to be built and copied to the `site-packages` directory successfully.

Comment: This just saved my day. Have been going crazy trying to install it in my virtualenv. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An update for 2015 on this issue.
I ran into this installing Pycurl on a Mac running Yosemite. I changed line **150** in `setup.py` as shown below:

```
for option in ["--libs", "--static-libs"]:
```

to:

```
for option in ["--libs"]:
```

Then ran:

```
$>python setup.py install
```

Installation worked perfectly after this!